# EFCore- Update Entity with Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I've two entities:

```
public class Clientdetails
{
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
 public string CompanyName { get; set; }
 public sbyte IndustryId { get; set; }
 public int BusinessModelId { get; set; }
 public Logincredentials Client { get; set; }
}

public partial class Logincredentials
{
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public sbyte RoleId { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public Rolemaster Role { get; set; }
public Clientdetails Clientdetails { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update the ClientDetails entity and along with it I want to update Logincredentials entity too. It is navigation property.
I've tried following code:

```
public Clientdetails UpdateClient(Clientdetails client)
{
  var details =  _unitOfWork.ClientDetailsRepository.FindBy(c => c.ClientId == client.ClientId).Include(c=>c.Client).SingleOrDefault();
 _entities.Entry(details).State = EntityState.Modified;
 _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm passing data like this:

```
{"clientId":1,"companyName":"Hewlett Packard1",
"industryId":2,"businessModelId":2,
"client":{"userId":1,"email":"priya.dave@xyz.com","isActive":true}
}
```

It updated fields of ClientDetails entity but it does not update properties of navigation property, i.e. LoginCredentials.

If I manually assign properties then it works:

```
 var details =  _unitOfWork.ClientDetailsRepository.FindBy(c => c.ClientId == client.ClientId).Include(c=>c.Client).SingleOrDefault();

if (details != null)
{  
if (client.Client != null)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.Client.Email))
{
details.Client.Email = client.Client.Email;
}
}
}
```

But I want to get rid of manual assignment. If it works when there is manual assignment, why its not working if I simply assign my input modified entity to the details object?
What have I missed here?

Comment: I do not have C# environment in front of me. Can you try details.State = EntityState.Modified; instead of _entities.Entry(details).State = EntityState.Modified; ?

Comment: It is not allowing me to do so. details is the object of type Clientdetails entity.

Comment: So you receive client in your method and try to change it. Can you try to simply set client.State?

Comment: within mapping entities only can deduce, i recommend instead of receive in updatecliente the cliendetails entity send a dto. so if you mapping is 1 to 1 should include the FK in the child entity if your wish from both sides get data so you should will create many to many relationship. one to one http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: Dto is already having FK. Here in LognCredentails table's UserId =ClientDetails table's ClientId.